# PyGTK system tray icon app runs two instances and closes both when user quits only one

Tags: python, pygtk

Good evening!

I'm writing a simple system tray app for Linux that checks for system updates using Python and GTK.  So far, I have the basic functionality, the app runs, displays an icon, and by right-clicking there is a menu with a few more options.  The problem comes about when I try to change the gtk.StatusIcon to a different image, rather than "swapping" the original icon for the "alert" icon, it creates a second icon in the tray (so now the standard icon and the alert icon are side by side) and when quitting the alert icon instance of the app, closes both.

This particular app is in two parts (code below), the back-end script that runs within an hourly cron job, and the GUI (system tray icon) which can be run as auto-started and/or via the applications menu.

I have read through the PyGTK documentation, but nothing that I saw explains how to switch (swap) the icons "in-place".  I'm sure that I am missing something and would appreciate any constructive input from a second pair of eyes.

Here's the "back-end" code:

```
import time
import subprocess
import logging
import lupdater

# Create the log, set level to DEBUG so that all messages are available
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/lupdater.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

# Global package list
paclist = []

class Pacman():
    '''Provides functions to call pacman and update the repos, as well as
    return a list with number of updates. '''
    def pac_update(self):
        '''Updates the repositories, notifies the user.'''
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/notify-send', 'Updating repositories for update check...'], shell=False)

        upd = subprocess.Popen('sudo pacman -Syy', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = upd.communicate()

    def pac_list(self):
        '''Creates a list of packages needing to be updated and counts them,
        displays the count in a notification for user action.'''
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/notify-send', 'Checking for updates...'], shell=False)

        # Clean up the list from previous checks so that we keep an accurate count.
        if len(paclist) > 0:
            for i in paclist:
                paclist.remove(i)

        lst = subprocess.Popen('pacman -Qu', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        for line in lst.stdout:
            line.rstrip('\r\n')
            paclist.append(line)

        numupdates = len(paclist)

        if numupdates >= 1:
            subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/notify-send', '%s %s %s' % ('You have', numupdates, 'updates available!')], shell=False)
            # Here we set the status icon to change and start blinking
            lupblinker = lupdater.SystrayApp()
            lupblinker.blinker()
            logging.info(time.ctime() + ': lupdater had %s updates available.\n' % (numupdates))
        else:
            subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/notify-send', 'Your system is already up to date! :)'], shell=False)
            logging.info(time.ctime() + ': No updates available, system is up to date.')
        # "Future-proofing"
        return numupdates, paclist

    def pac_check_list(self, paclist):
        # For now only checks for kernel updates, packages named "linux".
        # TODO: Check for kernel modules such as video drivers that require
        # a system restart or manual initialization.
        critical = []
        if len(paclist) > 0:
            for i in paclist:
                if i.startswith('linux'):
                    critical.append(i)

        if len(critical) >= 1:
            for i in critical:
                subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/notify-send',
                             '%s %s' % (i, 'is a critical update, it requires a system restart to take effect.')], shell=False)

                logging.info(time.ctime() + ': Critical update detected, user notified via notify-send.')
        return critical, paclist

def run_me(x):
    logging.info(time.ctime() + ': lupdater now running with sleep enabled process.')
    # Meat and Potatoes
    p = Pacman()
    p.pac_update()
    p.pac_list()
    p.pac_check_list(paclist)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 0
    run_me(x)enter code here
```

And here is the "GUI" code for the systray app:

```
import gtk
import subprocess
import lupdaterapi

class SystrayApp():

    def __init__(self):
        self.tray = gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.tray.set_from_file('/usr/share/icons/lupdater.png')
        self.tray.connect('popup-menu', self.on_right_click)
        self.tray.set_tooltip('Lemur Updater')
        self.lapi = lupdaterapi

    def blinker(self):
        self.tray.set_from_file('/usr/share/icons/lupdater-alert.png')
        self.tray.set_blinking(True)

    def on_right_click(self, icon, event_button, event_time):
        self.make_menu(event_button, event_time)
        if self.tray.set_blinking() == True:
        self.tray.set_blinking(False)
        self.tray.set_from_file('/usr/share/icons/lupdater.png')

    def make_menu(self, event_button, event_time):
        menu = gtk.Menu()

    # show about dialog
        about = gtk.MenuItem('About')
        about.show()
        menu.append(about)
        about.connect('activate', self.show_about_dialog)

    # add run item for manual updates
        run = gtk.MenuItem('Check Updates')
        run.show()
        menu.append(run)
        run.connect('activate', self.lapi.run_me)

        #add log checker, open in leafpad for now
        chklog = gtk.MenuItem('View Log')
        chklog.show()
        menu.append(chklog)
        chklog.connect('activate', self.show_log)

        # add quit item
        quit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        quit.show()
        menu.append(quit)
        quit.connect('activate', gtk.main_quit)

        menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu,
                event_button, event_time, self.tray)

    def  show_about_dialog(self, widget):
        about_dialog = gtk.AboutDialog()
        about_dialog.set_destroy_with_parent (True)
        about_dialog.set_icon_name ('Lemur Updater')
        about_dialog.set_name('Lemur Updater')
        about_dialog.set_version('1.3b')
        about_dialog.set_comments((u'System Tray interface to the Lemur Updater'))
        about_dialog.set_authors([u'Brian Tomlinson <darthlukan@gmail.com>'])
        about_dialog.run()
        about_dialog.destroy()

    def show_log(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/leafpad /tmp/lupdater.log', shell=True)

# Let's roll!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    SystrayApp()
    gtk.main()
```

Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a name and a title for the icon?

Comment: I have not.  I'll have to do more reading to find that particular set of instructions in the GTK documentation.  Thanks for the idea!